# Альтернативы для: «как раз»

Tags: грамотная-речь

На что можно было бы заменить ***Как раз***?

Comment: **Не существует** _внеконтекстных_ "альтернатив" для механической подстановки. Приведите пример, из которого было бы ясно, в каком значении вас интересует данное выражение - грубо говоря, "левый ботинок пришёлся как раз по ноге" или "как раз в этот день он не мог прийти".

Answer (score 1):

На синонимы, а их предлагают [словари](https://classes.ru/all-russian/russian-dictionary-synonyms-term-578.htm). Я выбрала слово, на мой взгляд, "ближайшее" - *аккурат*, и вот что высыпалось:

> прямо, чик-в-чик, в точности, как раз, в аккурат, точно, именно, ни
>   больше ни меньше, ровным счетом, ровно, точь-в-точь, копейка, тютелька
>   в тютельку, тик-в-тик, без отклонений, совершенно точно.